# Manually specify remapping of specific linking symbols

Tags: c, linux, linker, ld, symbols

Without modifying these two source files, is there a way to take the object files produced by compiling them, and convincing a linker to link `foo` in main_v1.c to `bar` in bar.c?

**main_v1.c**

```
void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts("bar()!");
}
```

Modifying the object files themselves is fair game but assume that we might not even have the source code available. The platform is Linux.

---

By insisting on a modest change to main_v1.c, and linking in an additional "mapping" object file, here's a way to almost get the desired result with just standard C.

**main_v2.c**

```
extern void (*const foo)(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

**bar.c** is unchanged.

**map.c**

```
void bar(void);
void (*const foo)(void) = bar;
```

If the object files are compiled with lto, the function pointer dereference is even elided (using a recent gcc). This is a pretty good result but if `main()` is modified to have a direct call to `bar()`, then `bar()` itself is inlined after linking so there's room for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a job for the [GNU `ld`
`--wrap` option](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html)

You have, we assume, a `main_v1.o` compiled and perhaps unchangeable from your
`main_v1.c` and likewise a `bar.o` compiled from your `bar.c`.

Now write another source file:

**wrap.c**

```
extern void bar(void);

void __wrap_foo(void)
{
    bar();
}
```

Compile it to `wrap.o` and link it with the prior object files like so:

```
$ gcc -c wrap.c
$ gcc -o prog -Wl,--wrap=foo main_v1.o bar.o wrap.o
```

Then:

```
$ ./prog
bar()!
```